# How do I change Vim splitting key-mapping?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I have recently started learning Vim, and I don't like the default key-mapping of splitting windows in Vim. That is, I don't like to enter C-w and then S for horizontal and v for vertical, and moving focus by C-w jkhl or up-down,left-right.

I will like to have 'h' for splitting horizontally and 'v' for splitting vertically when in Normal Mode, without entering C-w. How can this be done? And also, does anyone know of a sane-ish config for changing focus in windows, because I am not sure if that makes sense without C-w.

Thanks.

Comment: Changing mappings can cause problems as other plugins override them There are plugins eg https://github.com/wesQ3/vim-windowswap that help with moving windows. and things like `nmap <leader>s<left>   :leftabove  vnew<CR>` that maps `,s<left>` to create a new buffer on the left above. I use `,` as my leader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a good answer as I can't remember where I got these from but in my `_vimrc` (`.vimrc` on windows)

This lot moves between buffer ie `Alt right arrow` moves to the next buffer right etc

```
    nmap <silent> <A-Right> :wincmd l<CR>
    nmap <silent> <A-Up> :wincmd k<CR>
    nmap <silent> <A-Down> :wincmd j<CR>
    nmap <silent> <A-Left> :wincmd h<CR>
```

**Update**
Vim uses a concept of a leader, ie a standard key followed by another key(s), to make commands easier. See `:h <Leader>`. It defaults to backspace in the default installation i use `let mapleader = ","` as I find `,sw(leftarrow)` easier than `backspace(leftarrow)`. What it means is for eg `nmap <leader>q :q!<cr>` means typing `,q` quits the current buffer without saving it.
**END Update**

These commands remaps vim commands to a shorter command using the `leader` command eg to create new buffer at the top  left of your buffers use `leader>sw<left>` where `<left>` means the left arrow

```
    nmap <leader>sw<left>  :topleft  vnew<CR>
    nmap <leader>sw<right> :botright vnew<CR>
    nmap <leader>sw<up>    :topleft  new<CR>
    nmap <leader>sw<down>  :botright new<CR>
    nmap <leader>s<left>   :leftabove  vnew<CR>
    nmap <leader>s<right>  :rightbelow vnew<CR>
    nmap <leader>s<up>     :leftabove  new<CR>
    nmap <leader>s<down>   :rightbelow new<CR>
```

Comment: I didn't understand the `<leader>` part of your answer. I am a beginner, so can you please re-explain in simpler terms?

Comment: Hi. Hope the update helped.

Comment: I'm no longer a programmer and even when I was I hated speaking in *nix speak, which help files are written in, so my answers are based on English :)